# Show last active div on refresh JS

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, navigationbar, page-refresh

I have a fairly basic navigation tab on a single-page website that shows/hides divs. However, when I refresh the page, it goes back to the landing "page" div instead of staying on the current tab. I am using the following JS to switch between tabs and I would like to keep using this method if possible:

```
var links = document.getElementById('navs').getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var i = 0, link; link = links[i]; i++) {
    link.onclick = showContent;

    // Hide content divs by default
    var contentdiv = getContentDiv(link)
    if (contentdiv == null){
        continue;
    }
    contentdiv.style.display = 'none';
}

// Show the first content div
if(links.length > 0) showContent.apply(links[0]);
var current;

function showContent() {

    // hide old content
   if(current) current.style.display = 'none';

   current = getContentDiv(this);
   if(!current) return true;

   current.style.display = 'inline-block';

   return true;

}

function getContentDiv(link) {

    var linkTo = link.getAttribute('href');
    console.log(linkTo);

    // Make sure the link is meant to go to a div
    if(linkTo.substring(0, 2) != '#!') return;
    linkTo = linkTo.substring(2);
    return document.getElementById(linkTo);

}
```

I know it refreshes to the landing div because of
`if(links.length > 0) showContent.apply(links[0]);`
However, I was hoping to use this method and store the link iteration number in a variable called current_link and then be able to call `if(links.length > 0) showContent.apply(links[current_link]);` or even `if(links.length > 0) showContent.apply(current_link);`

I have tried a couple ways, but it ends up just saving either the first or last tab in the navigation bar. Also the page refreshes to the default div, but the url stays the same. EX. The URL is http://example.com/#!tab1 even though the page is displaying http://example.com/#!home

This is the html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" id= "navs" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <div class="navbar-brand"> 
                        <a id="logo" href="#!home"><img id="logo-pic" src="images/name.png" alt="" width="50%" height="auto"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="navbar" id="navbar-collapse-1">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-right navbar-nav">
                            <a href="#!home"></a>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#!tab1">tab1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">tab2</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right pull-center">
                                          <li><a href="#!tab21">tab21</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="#!tab22">tab22</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">tab3</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right pull-center">
                                          <li><a href="images/about/Resume2016.pdf" target="_blank">resume</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="#!tab31">tab31</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="#!tab32">tab32</a></li>
                                        </ul>

                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#!tab4">tab4</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#!tab5">tab5</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to persist page state is to leverage the url history.

E.g. when the user clicks on a tab, instead of just doing the navigation:

- Create a hashchange event handler

`window.onhashchange = () => { ... };`

or:

`window.addEventListener('hashchange', () => ...);`

So you might do something like:

```
const navigate = () => open_tab(location.hash.substr(1)); // get rid of the '#'
window.addEventListener('hashchange', navigate);
```

You also want to navigate when the page loads:

`navigate();`

- Now, when the user clicks a tab, or whatever, change the hash of the page location:

`location.hash = "tab1";`

This is a little extra work but the benefits are huge:

- Refreshing the page works as expected
- If the user bookmarks the page, they bookmark the state of the UI
- Forward and backward navigation now work as expected.